# Gridview eval condition is not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having database table with subject,faulty,hour.In the hour value am storing like 1,2,3,4 and 5 in the database.I want to disable the already clicked check box but in my result it is blocking the whole row not the particular check box.help me out from these problem.I have uploaded my sample code and database schema below

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
         <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="datee" HeaderText="Day/Hour" SortExpression="datee" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour1">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkColumn1" runat="server" />
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean((int)Eval("hour"))%>' Enabled='<%# Convert.ToBoolean((int)Eval("hour")!=1) %>' OnCheckedChanged="chkHour1_CheckedChanged"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour2">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkColumn2" runat="server"/>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour2" runat="server" Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean((int)Eval("hour"))%>' Enabled='<%# Convert.ToBoolean((int)Eval("hour")!=2) %>' OnCheckedChanged="chkHour2_CheckedChanged"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour3">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkColumn3" runat="server"/>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour3" runat="server" Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean((int)Eval("hour"))%>' Enabled='<%# Convert.ToBoolean((int)Eval("hour")!=3) %>' OnCheckedChanged="chkHour3_CheckedChanged"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour4">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkColumn4" runat="server"/>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour4" runat="server" Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean((int)Eval("hour"))%>' Enabled='<%# Convert.ToBoolean((int)Eval("hour")!=4) %>' OnCheckedChanged="chkHour4_CheckedChanged"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour5">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkColumn5" runat="server"/>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour5" runat="server" Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean((int)Eval("hour"))%>' Enabled='<%# Convert.ToBoolean((int)Eval("hour")!=5) %>' OnCheckedChanged="chkHour5_CheckedChanged"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>





using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter("select DISTINCT datee,hour from tblfac order by datee", con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("dt");
                cmd.Fill(dt);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
```

[image]

I clicked only 1 check box value but it is blocking the whole column.help me out from the problem

Comment: Why are you using same variable `hour` for all the 5 checkboxes? Don't you have different variables for that? Can you show us your SQL output?

Comment: It is time table so i want to use hour only

Comment: You have to configure it on the RowDataBound event, to disable the checkbox that has been checked.

Comment: What to add in rowdatabound event

Comment: I have changed my code and its working its blocking that particular value but value is repeating in the result.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, the problem is that all five checkboxes in the row are checked, regardless of what the value of hour is.  This is because you are using

```
Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean((int)Eval("hour"))%>'
```

to set the value of the checkbox.  You are converting the integer value of hour to a boolean value.  Convert.ToBoolean will translate any non-zero integer to true, so as long as hour isn't zero, the checkbox will be checked.

Working example:

Creating datasource in code-behind:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable("dt");
dt.Columns.Add("datee", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("hour", typeof(int));

dt.Rows.Add("06-Jul-15 12:00:00 AM",1);
dt.Rows.Add("07-Jul-15 12:00:00 AM",2);
dt.Rows.Add("08-Jul-15 12:00:00 AM",3);
dt.Rows.Add("09-Jul-15 12:00:00 AM",4);
dt.Rows.Add("10-Jul-15 12:00:00 AM",5);

GridView1.DataSource = dt;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Gridview:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
     <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="datee" HeaderText="Day/Hour" SortExpression="datee" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean((int)Eval("hour")==1)%>' Enabled='<%# Convert.ToBoolean((int)Eval("hour")!=1) %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour2" runat="server" Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean((int)Eval("hour")==2)%>' Enabled='<%# Convert.ToBoolean((int)Eval("hour")!=2) %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour3">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour3" runat="server" Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean((int)Eval("hour")==3)%>' Enabled='<%# Convert.ToBoolean((int)Eval("hour")!=3) %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour4">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour4" runat="server" Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean((int)Eval("hour")==4)%>' Enabled='<%# Convert.ToBoolean((int)Eval("hour")!=4) %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Hour5">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkHour5" runat="server" Checked='<%#Convert.ToBoolean((int)Eval("hour")==5)%>' Enabled='<%# Convert.ToBoolean((int)Eval("hour")!=5) %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Results showing only one box checked, and that box disabled:

[image: Resulting Gridview]